# How to prevent the selected button in tableview when scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have Tableview with multiple sections & Many data in tableview cell. In my situation is only select one  one radio button in one section. so we select the radio button at one section then it scroll down and select the another section when we come to up all radio button are unselected how to save the button state. so resolve this issue we create one NSMutable array to save the button state but by this the issue are not resolve.I am writing this code in swift.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        cell=table_view.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier,forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tablecell
        let manyCells : Bool = arrayForBool .objectAtIndex(indexPath.section).boolValue

        if (!manyCells) {
        }
        else
        {
            cell.lbl_text.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            Section=indexPath.section
            cell.tag = indexPath.row + 1
            cell.btn_radio.tag=indexPath.row
            cell.btn_radio.selected = arr_Selection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
         }

        if indexPath.isEqual(selectedIndex)
        {
            cell.btn_radio.selected = arr_Selection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        }
        else {
            cell.btn_radio.selected = false
        }

     return cell
} 

@IBAction func btn_radio(sender: AnyObject)
{ 
     let Section_count = table_view.numberOfSections
     let rowCount = table_view.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)
     print("rowCount\(rowCount)")

     for j in 0..<Section_count
     {
           if j==indexPath.section
           {
                for i in 0..<rowCount
                {
                      if i==indexPath.row
                      {
                            selectedIndex = indexPath
                            arr_Selection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]=true
                            let range = NSMakeRange(indexPath.section, 1)
                            let sectionToReload = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: range)
                            table_view .reloadSections(sectionToReload, withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

                        }
                  }
            }
     }

}
```

this code is use by me to select the button its working but when scroll in tableview is not save the state of button selection how to resolve this.

Comment: what this piece of code is doing? for j in 0..<Section_count
            {
                if j==indexPath.section
                {
                    for i in 0..<rowCount
                    {

                        if i==indexPath.row
                        {???

Comment: its use for select one particular section one row so  we use this

Comment: ok, but this code do nothing! You do not use i and j inside last if... it just heating the CPU and drain battery charge))

Comment: looks like indexPath.isEqual(selectedIndex) is always false, check this

Comment: No all time which cell we select then it true another once is false

Comment: if you select only one cell, you do not need array for storing flags. Use one optional variable selectedIndex

Comment: I am using this but when we scroll all buttons are unselected so we use this but condition is same

Comment: Create one array of integer with capacity of sections count. Fill it by -1 value if cell is not selected at sections. Write value of IndexPath.row to array section item when tap happens . Compare it at cellForRowAtIndexPath when redrawing cell.

Comment: pls explain by example

Comment: how to compare it

Comment: save the selection mode in the model class . and tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath in this method compare and update the cell status

Comment: Comparation of selected state is cell.btn_radio.selected = arr_Selection[indexPath.section] == 1

Comment: can you explain by example

Comment: pls explain by example i dont understand because i am new in swift Ramkumar & Yuri